# How do you analyze if an OpenMage project needs to switch to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, openmage

How do you analyze the **urgency** of migration of a project (which is to be done is almost taken for granted) that in 2021 asks you the question: should I go from Magento 1.9 to 2?

Assuming that the e-commerce in question already has important things for the PCI DSS like: the card data is managed by a gateway and does not go through the e-commerce, they are already using OpenMage.

I would like to know a little what criteria you considered so as to enrich my idea...

Answer (score 0):

Although the payment processor's gateway might be PCI compliant, the response and further transaction details are coming back to a platform which is no longer compliant (since there are no updates and security patches for the 1.x versions), which I would say still might pose a problem.

I am, for one thing, very skeptical on how any agency can provide a commitment that they will solve any issue in Magento core or any security issue that goes out in the wild. I would always go with official recommendations and upgrade on time, apply the security patches and keep my store safe, so yes, this means replatforming to latest Magento 2 asap.

Moreover, I think it's important to also take into consideration Magento 1.x's compatibility with PHP versions, for example. In M1, you would have a max of PHP 7.2 supported, a version which became obsolete in November 2020 (see [official site](https://www.php.net/eol.php)). The fact that the PHP version is already deprecated alone rings the alarm for any production website and I would consider replatforming asap.

The same happens to many other services that Magento needs or integrates with, which remain out of official support and can lead to major security issues since you cannot upgrade your Magento core to be compatible with the latest patched versions.

Talking about deprecation, same goes to the 3rd party extensions which gradually fade away. Vendors no longer provide support for the extensions which were released for integration with Magento 1. The goal becomes now to facilitate and promote the Magento 2 installation customizations.

I would also think that the upgrade topic is also a question of business growth and needs. Magento 2 (even if it's the open source version) comes with many powerful implementations that you can't find in the Magento 1.x versions, so I would definitely take this into account, specially on the long run.

And after all, why not consider benefiting of the latest *'bling-bling'* since this is what the competitors use and this will promote your business in the future?

Comment: Very interesting point of view, especially that of third-party modules that may decide to stop investing in Magento 1. OpenMage is supporting the new versions of PHP.

Comment: Hope you are not angry with me, but that gives -1. Question was about OM, not M1 and even then I'd update from M1 to OM, instead of M2.

Comment: uhmm, the way I saw it it was about **'should I go from Magento 1.9 to 2'** and expressed my opinion.

Comment: Understand, but OpenMage is not (really) comparable to plain M1. It it "M1", but with hundreds of fixes and improvments. If OM would not exists, i'd agree with this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: https://medium.com/swlh/adobe-magento-2-4-vs-openmage-magento-1-9-open-source-performance-2021-c710406d3dc9

> Magento 2 is completely broken both UI and PHP Framework, and without a custom solution, it doesn’t float. **Avoid it at all costs! Use and invest in the custom solutions created by the community!**

---

I disaggree with Dianas answer.

The answer is more about vanilla M1 w/o much knowlegde about OpenMage.

> Although the payment processor's gateway might be PCI compliant, the response and further transaction details are coming back to a platform which is no longer compliant **(since there are no updates and security patches for the 1.x versions)**, which I would say still might pose a problem.

OpenMage partners up with [sansec](https://sansec.io/?openmage) and there are [security patches](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/security/advisories?state=published). I also don't see any problems with payment providers. There are far more M1 installations than M2 and no one will stop supporting M1/OpenMage because they want to make money and not force customers to do something.

> Moreover, I think it's important to also take into consideration Magento 1.x's compatibility with PHP versions, for example. In M1, you would have a max of PHP 7.2 supported, a version which became obsolete in November 2020 (see official site).

OpenMage dropped PHP5 time ago and supports 7.0-7.4 (PHP8 support incoming). It supports composer2 and mysql8, so it seems more up to date as M2.

> Talking about deprecation, same goes to the 3rd party extensions which gradually fade away. Vendors no longer provide support for the extensions which were released for integration with Magento 1. The goal becomes now to facilitate and promote the Magento 2 installation customizations.

I think that is only half right. Yes, providers stepped back with feature improvements, but any serious one (those with livetime support) will prodived patches (independent of new releases). I want to mention [Amasty](https://amasty.com/), that latly provided a patch for their FPC module. Just raise an issue and wait a few days for a fix. (I opend a few tickets there, e.g. regarding to php-version updates and all got fixed in time).

OpenMage [works on being recognized](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/990) as own project to have "valid" numbers about running installations. This makes it easier for the argumentation towards 3rd-party vendors to support the project.

E.g. https://trends.builtwith.com/shop/OpenMage

Within 3 month (?) 15k shops have been detected running a late OpenMage version. OM exists for many years and before M1 went EOL, it had around 190 forks (after serveral years). Some month later it has +300 forks and is activly maintained.

> And after all, why not consider benefiting of the latest 'bling-bling' since this is what the competitors use and this will promote your business in the future?

If you dont need that 'bling-bling' you should not bother about what others do. Dotmailer, Braintree, Yopto, ... How many shops make use of MSI or stuff like GraphQl?

What about performance? M2 is only faster with FPC, and M1 also has FPC extensions. M1 is easier to maintain, less resources needed, less costs.

---

**If you do not rely on M2 features, that aren't availble for M1 (even not with paid extensions) I see no reason to upgrade from OpenMage to M2.**

(If you still use an official M1 version i'd highly recommend to update to OpenMage - to have security fixes! E.g. even the last 1.9.4.5 release is affected by [Cardbleed](https://sansec.io/research/cardbleed) exploit, OM isn't it ...)